# Model Relation in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using active admin to add a row in my table CustomPage as well as MenuItem.
This is my menu model

```
class MenuItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :custom_page
  after_create :set_url
  def set_url
    @menu_item = MenuItem.all
    url = "/pages/"+@menu_item.last.name.split(" ").join("_")
    @menu_item.last.update(url:url)
end
```

and this is my custom page model

```
    class CustomPage < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :menu_items
      after_create :set_custom_url

      def set_custom_url
        @custom_page = CustomPage.all
        url = "/pages/view/"+@custom_page.last.page_name.split(" ").join("_")
        @custom_page.last.update(url:url)  
      end
    end
```

and this is my controller

```
class CustomPageController < ActionController::Base
  layout 'calculator'
  def load_content
    @menu_item = MenuItem.where(url: "/pages/"+params[:page_name])
    if @menu_item.first.custom_page.present?
      @description = @menu_item.first.custom_page.description
    else  
      @description = "CUSTOM PAGE NOT FOUND..."  
    end
  end

  def show_custom_page
    @custom_view = CustomPage.where(url: "/pages/view/"+params[:page])
    if @custom_view.first.present?
      @description = @custom_view.first.description      
    end
  end
end
```

and my routes are

```
get '/pages/:page_name' => 'custom_page#load_content'
get '/pages/view/:page' => 'custom_page#show_custom_page'
```

One is i can create a menu item and link with any of the custom pages created. So that when i click on one menu and view the corresponding custom page. In this way i can create any number of custom pages which will not be shown in front end..

Second route is because i want to view the created custom custom pages which are not linked with menu items. I can view the page by copying the url from custom_pages table into the browser..

Thing is when i do this way i need two view pages, two controller methods.. and two routes.

Is there any way i can make it in single route..single method and single view..
here is so far i have tried..
 In my controller

```
def load_content
        @menu_item = MenuItem.where(url: "/pages/"+params[:page_name])
        @custom_page = CustomPage.where(url: "/pages/"+params[:page_name])
        if @menu_item.first.custom_page.present?
          @description = @menu_item.first.custom_page.description
        elsif @custom_page.first.present?
          @description = @custom_page.first.description
        else
          @description = "CUSTOM PAGE NOT FOUND..."  
        end
      end
```

and i removed all other codes from controller and deleted the second route and second view.

But i get an error at line `if @menu_item.first.custom_page.present?` when i tried to load it just via url.. custom_page not defined.. Is there any way to do this..or should i stick with my old method

Comment: What is the question again?

Comment: `@custom_page = CustomPage.all` to just get `@custom_page.last` is an ***amazing*** perf killer unless you're using Rails 4